# Backslash operator in linux shell script doesn't work as it should

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've got a simple shell script that should  open a new terminal window with multiple (three) tabs.

```
open_gnome_terminal () {
  gnome-terminal \
        --window -- bash -ic "echo tab1; exec bash;" \  
        --tab  -- bash -ic "echo tab2; exec bash;" \
        --tab  -- bash -ic "echo tab3; exec bash;"
}

open_gnome_terminal
```

However, when I run the script via `. ./myScript` I get the following error:

```
--window: command not found
--tab: command not found
```

I also tried to run that script all in a single command in terminal and it worked fine, so my question is why backslash operator doesn't work properly in my shell script and how do I fix that?
I use Linux Ubuntu 23.04

**EDIT:**
I removed spaces after backslashes and the errors are gone now. Though I still didn't achieve the desired result of a new terminal window with 3 tabs  (It only opens up a window with one tab)

Comment: Perhaps there are whitespaces after the `\\`

Comment: Are you using LF or CRLF as line endings? `od script` will tell you

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano I tried minimizing my script to a one-liner like so: ```gnome-terminal \\ --window -- bash -ic "echo tab1; exec bash;" \\ --tab -- bash -ic "echo tab2; exec bash;" \\ --tab -- bash -ic "echo tab3; exec bash;"``` It no longer throws any errors, but a new window opens only with one tab.

Comment: @knittl I use LF as line endings

Comment: There are two spaces after your backslash in the second line (see comment by Diego)

Comment: @knittl sorry, got it now. I did remove all the spaces after backslash. I no longer get any errors, but my new terminal windows opens up with a single tab and not with three tabs

Comment: Try running it as just `./script`. Also, you may want add `set -vx` at the top of your script to see how the shell ultimately processes your cmd. Also be aware that using `script` as a name may conflict with `/usr/bin/script` at some point. Better to get into habit of name things `myScript`, `myTest` etc. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Sadly, running it as `./script` provides the same result (a terminal window with single tab instead of 3 tabs desired). Also `set -vx` doesn't seem to make any changes. (My script isn't named as `script` though, I referred to it as `script` to keep it simple :) )

Comment: I didn't expect for `set -vx` to make any change in *how* your script would work. It should show you the exact command that the shell executes, preceded by the  `+` char. Looking carefully at that final line that is executed may show some hint as to why you're not getting all of your tabs. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Got it, thanks. Final line executed looks right. It seems that I chain command options somehow incorrectly, because `gnome-terminal --window --tab --tab` works fine and when adding a command to execute within each tab bash it opens only one tab and ignores the rest

Comment: "*`--tab --tab`  works fine"* .. Good debugging! but I'm not a `gnome-terminal` user. It's my recollection that the `screen` utility can read a `.screenrc` (and other files (I think)), to have a scripted setup. Maybe there is an option like that for `gnome-terminal`?  ... `man gnome-t...` (-;! Good luck.

Comment: Or maybe do a broader web-search for "my favorite gnome-terminal options" etc. Cheers!

Comment: @shellter Thanks! Now trying to research on that. Reading gnome-terminal manual but couldn't find anything helpful yet. I'll make sure to update and resolve my question in case I'll get my script for work. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: There may be a developers email list for g-term, but don't phrase your post as "I found a bug" . There are usually 2-3 lists, 1) general, 2) releases, 3) developer details. Search thru the general archive for `--tag`, see what you find, then post a question to general asking if your use-case is supported, and where you are going wrong. (don't bother the developers on their details msg list). ... OK, that's about all I know on this topic (-;!. Goooood luck!

Comment: @shellter Thank you, I'll definitely do that to try solving my issue. Best of luck!

Comment: The follow-up question about gnome-terminal should be a separate question from the initial question about backslashes. By contrast, if you _only_ have answers about gnome-terminal and no questions about the trailing spaces, consider updating your question to fit those answers so people with the same problem can actually find them.

Comment: And .... one more thing (-;! .. Consider getting your tabbed windows using `screen` or `tmux`. (I believe `tmux` tabs look more like a window's tab). That is, start your gnome-terminal, but then call `screen/tmux` to actually create your tabs (interal to those apps). Using these have the feature of leaving your workspace in place, even if you disconnect and later connect again (using `screen -r`). Your use case may dictate otherwise. Good luck!

Comment: Aside from the erroneous space after the `--`, look at the file with a hex editor. Could it be that there is a space chracter after the first backslash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is:

```
open_gnome_terminal () {
  gnome-terminal \
        --window -- bash -ic "echo tab1; exec bash;" \  
        --tab  -- bash -ic "echo tab2; exec bash;" \
        --tab  -- bash -ic "echo tab3; exec bash;"
}
```

This invokes `gnome-terminal` with one option `--window`.

Then option processing is terminated by `--`.

The rest of the "line" is a program to run and its arguments:

```
bash -ic "echo tab1; exec bash;" --tab -- bash -ic "echo tab2; exec bash;" --tab -- bash -ic "echo tab3; exec bash;"
```

`bash` reads a command from the argument following `-c`.
The next argument (`--tab`) is used to set its `$0`.
The remaining arguments are ignored (since you did not refer to them in the first `-c` command).

---

To do what you want, the `--command` option is deprecated but appears to still work on my machine:

```
open_gnome_terminal() {
    gnome-terminal \
        --window --command 'bash -ic "echo tab1; exec bash"' \
        --tab    --command 'bash -ic "echo tab2; exec bash"' \
        --tab    --command 'bash -ic "echo tab3; exec bash"'
}
```

My manpage warns that this is not an actual shell commandline. I would probably put more complicated code into a shell script and invoke that (`--command /path/to/my/script`)

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of extra spaces after the backslashes.

Try copy-pasting the script in vi, then in insert mode place the cursor before `--window`, delete spaces until the dash is just after `\` of the previous line. Hit enter to make sure everything is well formatted. Repeat for the other lines

Comment: I removed all the spaces after backslashes. I no longer get any errors, but i do get my new terminal window with a single tab (not 3 I want).

Comment: also turn on the `vi` `list` feature with `(Esc):set list` and you will see `$` at the end of each line. With the problem with trailing spaces, you'll see `...stuff...\ $` (where there is a space char after the `"\"` char. Good luck to all.